# write proc call back function implementation using file_operations not working

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm trying to implement a call back function when a proc file is written to from user space.  I'm using file_ops to specify the call backs.

```
struct msg_t {
    u32 length;
    u8 type;    
    u16 cmd;
    char[20] name;
    int number;
} msg_t
```

userspace.cpp

```
msg_t msg = {0};
// populate msg struct accordingly
fwrite(&msg, sizeof(msg), 1, stream);
fflush();
```

LKM.c

```
static ssize_t write_proc( struct file *filp, const char __user *buff, size_t len, loff_t *data){
msg_t *msg = NULL;
printk(KERN_ALERT "len: %zd\n", len);

msg = (msg_t *) kmalloc(sizeof(msg_t), GFP_KERNEL);
memset(msg, 0, sizeof(msg_t));
copy_from_user( msg, buff, sizeof(msg_t));

switch (msg->cmd)
    {
     //switch stuff
    }
kfree(msg);
return len;
}

static const struct file_operations fops = {
    .owner          = THIS_MODULE,
    .write          = write_proc,
};

static int __init o_init(void){
struct proc_dir_entry *proc_dir = proc_mkdir("app", NULL);
struct proc_dir_entry *proc_entry = proc_create("file", 0777, proc_dir, &fops);
}
```

So the above implementation worked with with the older implementation of the proc file system callbacks ie `create_proc_read_entry`.  When I write the `msg` struct from user space to the `/proc/app/file` there seems to be a loop and `len` is equal to 20 then it counts down until 0 then it starts over at the sizeof the `msg` struct then decrements a couple times then  stops.

```
len: 20
len: 19
len: 18
.
.
len: sizeof(msg)
.
.
```

I'm having a hard time getting a handle on the newer proc file implementation (with file_ops) so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What value does `write_proc` return?

Comment: I've been returning the length parameter.

Comment: And `len` is never changed? Could you log the return value? And what should happen when you get less than `sizeof(msg)` bytes?

Comment: len does change, len is the value that I'm printing out.  So it is decreasing starting from 20 down to 0 then starts over at the size of the struct then decreases a couple times then stops.  It's like the write_proc function is in a loop.  Nothing is suppose to happen when len is less than the struct it's just the behaviour that's happening.

Comment: Your file requires writing a `msg_t`, so you should return `-EINVAL` if you get fewer bytes, and return only how many bytes were actually handled.